# Mouse get stuck some times

Tags: mouse

When I Installed upuntu for the first time I log in and was going to update it like there were packages and I was trying to do other thing's like go on the web when the packages were going to be installed but the toachpad got stuck. I was wondering about this but I just don't know if it will do it again:( ???

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue?

Comment: This happens to my USB mouse on my desktop all the time since the last few versions or Ubuntu, sometimes it takes out just the mouse, sometimes it takes the keyboard with it... The only fix I have been able to come up with is to use a PS2 mouse... which works fine.. but it isn't my favorite mouse...

Answer (score 2):

Try running `sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse`.

This unloads and reloads the touchpad driver. Doing this might alleviate the problem, at least temporarily.

Comment: @tijybba This seems to me quite clearly to be an answer, and in no way to be an attempt to get information from the OP. Assuming you do think this is not an answer, can you explain why? (I've edited this to add more information about what this does, which might help clarify things.) What's valuable about this command is not what information it reveals, but what it actually does, which might fix the problem, at least temporarily.

Comment: Hmm, yes i am deleting my comment.